# Adding columns to Membership table. But cannot access them? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have the default membership table that was added automatically, then just used server explorer to add more columns, like `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc. In my code I can access all the default columns, but not the ones I created. Any thing special I need to do?

Here is how I access the table. using `user.` gives me all columns, but the one I created.

```
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;


    MembershipUser user = (MembershipUser)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(userName).ProviderUserKey;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not able to do that is because MembershipUser doesn't expose those properties. You will have to extend that class in order to do that and lot more which will be a lot of work. Also I wouldn't recommend modifying the existing membership tables.

You have two options:

1: Use built-in asp.net profiles as mentioned by Derek Beattie.
or

2: Create a separate table to store additional user details. Here's how you do that:

[Store-Additional Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs)

[Custom Table](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2009/01/27/storing-user-profile-into-a-custom-table-using-createuser-wizard-control.aspx)

In case if you want to go long route here is [how to extend existing membership API](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/34492).

Comment: Why would you recommend not modifying the existing membership tables? I could understand why wouldn't want to change/break their existing columns, but I really don't see any harm at all in just adding to them. Keep the same structure, add some columns. I can't imagine any problems with that..

Comment: @user3308043 yes you can add a column if you like, though those columns will not be available to directly as you will have to modify the stored procedures / and corresponding classes. One other reason was say Microsoft changing the Membership provider as they did recently with Identity Provider. Now say if you want to migrate to this new provider, you will need to do extra work than needed if you had default schema. "Not recommended" was/is mainly from MS and for those who don't really know the side-effects. So again it's kind of a grey-area.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said, but I'm looking at this from a raw data access point of view. If you simply want to add to that table, you can. Sure migration might be tough. Sure, sprocs won't be the same. But if you want to write ad-hoc SQL queries against added columns to the 'Users' or 'Membership' tables after you've added columns to them, you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to do that via custom profile fields.
http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/9/adding-custom-profile-fields.aspx

Comment: Absolutely. I'm definitely not a fan of that, however.

Answer (score 0):

**To add a new column named "FirstName":**

**Step 1:** Models/IdentityModels.cs

Add the following code to the "ApplicationUser" class:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**Step 2:**  Models/AccountViewModels.cs

Add the following code to the "RegisterViewModel" class:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**Step 3:**  Views/Register.cshtml

Add FirstName input textbox to the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>
```

**Step 4 :**

Go to Tools > NuGet Manager > Package Manager Console 
    Step A : Type “Enable-Migrations” and press enter 
    Step B : Type “ Add-Migration "FirstName" ” and press enter 
    Step C : Type “Update-Database” and press enter

i.e

```
    PM> Enable-Migrations
    PM> Add-Migration "FirstName"
    PM> Update-Database
```

Step 5:  Controllers/AccountController.cs

Go to Register Action and add "FirstName = model.FirstName" to the ApplicationUser 
i.e

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName}
```